# MS-SQL Server: Why does an Update-Statement not work within an If-Block?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why does the following not work?

The update statement is always executed, even the if statement evaluates to false. If I remove the update statement, the code works fine.

What's the correct way to do this?

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FOO' AND COLUMN_NAME ='BAR') = 1  
    BEGIN
        UPDATE FOO SET BAZ = BAR;
        alter table FOO alter column BAZ int not null;
    END
```

Comment: Add condition TABLE_SCHEMA ='???'

Comment: It's not *running* any of the code at all. You're getting an error (that you've failed to tell us about) during *compilation*. Imagine writing a method in java that uses reflection to determine whether a particular method exists on a type - but that same method also tries to call that method directly. You wouldn't expect that to work in java, why would you expect similar code to work in SQL?

Comment: The error is: "Illegal column name 'bar'". I don't see your point. What I'm trying to do is mainly to write an update statement which is executed based on a condition. SQL Server Management Studio compiles the code fine, the error is thrown during execution.

Comment: No, Management studio doesn't compile any code. The text of the batch is submitted to SQL Server itself. First, SQL Server tries to compile the batch. Whilst compiling the batch, it observes that there is no `bar` column and returns an error. It would only *run* the code if compilation succeeded.

Comment: @Illegal column name@  error mySql DBMS

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: So, what's the answer to my question, then? at Tapakah Ua: It is a Microsoft SQL server. I just translated the German error message "Ungültiger Spaltenname" to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to wrap the UPDATE statement in a  EXEC sp_executesql N statement. Don't forget to add two ' around the UPDATE statement.

```
IF (SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'FOO' AND COLUMN_NAME ='BAR') = 1  
    BEGIN
        EXEC sp_executesql N'UPDATE FOO SET BAZ = BAR';
        alter table FOO alter column BAZ int not null;
    END
```

This works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'FOO' AND COLUMN_NAME ='BAR')  
    BEGIN
        UPDATE FOO SET BAZ = BAR;
        alter table FOO alter column BAZ int not null;
    END
```

Comment: Does not work. I still get the error "Illegal column name 'bar'".

Comment: MySql != ms SQL